# How can I get path of setup.exe from custom action?

Tags: c#, windows, installation, directory

My setup.exe in e:\setup.exe, I tried this code:

```
System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
```

return c:\Windows\syswow64\

```
Application.ExecutablePath;
```

return c:\Windows\syswow64\MsiExec.exe

```
Application.StartupPath
```

return c:\Windows\syswow64\

I need something return e:\

Comment: you can use `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()` to get the current running process directory, you can also use `DriveInfo[] allDrives = DriveInfo.GetDrives();` to get all drives if that's what you are looking

Comment: The problem is that, at the point at which your code is running, it's running as a component of an `.msi` file which, as most indications are telling you, is actually executed by the `MsiExec.exe` program. If there *is* a way to access this information, you'll be looking for something MSI specific for accessing MSI properties, not generic .NET code looking at the current executable/working directory.

Answer (score 1):

```
using System.IO;
string exeDir = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
```

You can get exe full path by reflection also.

```
string exeLocation = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location;
```

You can this too.

```
string exeDir = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
string exeLocation = Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location;
```

One more way:

```
string dir = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase);
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, some of your suggestions return path where the application will be after installation but one of them return path of setup.exe

Comment: That is why I have posted multiple answers, as it was not well explained in the question:)

Comment: You can set the target path in  CustomActionData property and get in context parameters also

Answer (score 0):

To get current working directory use

```
Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
```

which locate under `System.IO`